# Usar updatemany no mongoose numa requisicao

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando fazer um *update/insert* com o **mongoose** ao finalizar uma requisição. Essa requisição me retorna, por exemplo:

```
let obj = [
    {nome: aaa,idade: 10},
    {nome: bbb,idade: 11},
    {nome: ccc,idade: 12},
]
```

E estou tentando salvar no mongo da seguinte forma: caso algum desses registros não exista, devem ser criados. Caso exista, atualize todas as informações do documento.

A forma que achei que seria a correta, lendo a documentação do mongo, seria:

```
updateMany({}, {$set: {nome:"obj.$.nome", idade: "obj.$.idade"}}, {upsert:true})
```

Mas eu devo estar fazendo alguma coisa errada, pq simplesmente não acontece nada, não insere dados, não da erro quando uso o `catch`.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

EDIT:
Fazendo um teste mais simples, pelo mongoose tentei

`model-do-contexto.updateMany({},{$set: {nome: 'abc'}},{upsert: true})`

E não funcionou. Mas fazendo direto pelo banco da seguinte forma

`db.contexo.updateMany({},{$set: {nome: 'abc'}},{upsert: true})`

Funcionou, mas eu ainda não sei como fazer funcionar pelo mongoose

Comment: você não precisa pegar o `db.seucontext.updateMany()` para fazer essa operação ? (Não sei nada disso, só que todos os lugares que eu vi, tinha algo dessa forma).

Fonte 1 : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany

Fonte 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038547/mongodb-update-every-document-on-one-field

Fonte 3: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

Caso o que eu falei não tenha nada a ver, só ignora kkk

Comment: Eu to usando o mongoose, ele me permite usar o `Model`, que no caso, eh oq vc chamou de contexto, entao ficaria algo assim: `exemplo.updateMany({...})`. Eu nao coloquei ali, pq queria colocar o foco na funcao de update. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri qual era o problema, no mongoose, obrigatoriamente eu preciso preciso passar o ultimo parâmetro que é uma função entao para resolver o problema inicial o codigo seria:

```
for(let n of obj){
   <contexto>.update({nome: n.nome}, {$set: {'idade':n.idade}}, {upsert: true},  
(err, doc)=>{
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(doc)
 })
}
```

Ou seja, precisei percorrer todos os objetos que vieram na minha requisição, e dar update um por um passando uma função como parâmetro no meu update. Ao sei se essa é a melhor forma de resolver isso, mas funcionou. Não vi nada disso nas documentações que olhei.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente você esqueceu de fechar a chave que está aberta logo antes do $set:

```
{$set: {nome:"obj.$.nome", idade: "obj.$.idade"}
```

Ela tem de ficar assim:

```
{$set: {nome:"obj.$.nome", idade: "obj.$.idade"}}
```

Comment: Eu errei na hora de digitar a pergunta, mas eu tinha colocado.

Comment: Tente o código a seguir:

`model-do-contexto.update({},{$set: {nome: 'abc'}},{multi: true, upsert: true})`

li a documentação do mongoose, e para update múltiplo é usada a função update() e nas opções dessa função é indicado com o `multi: true` que múltiplos documentos poderão ser atualizados.

Comment: Usando o updateMany, nao tem necessidade de passar o `{multi: true}`. Mas eu testei mesmo assim, e nao funcionou via codigo (mongoose), mas funcionou direto pelo banco ( como os outros testes que eu fiz )